# What are pros & cons of Passed Arrays vs Global Arrays in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

Ok, 2nd attempt at writing a Stack Overflow Question, so forgive me if this seems familiar.

I am rewriting an Excel Macro that was built over a 2 1/2 year period, frankenstein style (added to piecemeal).  One of the things I need to do is load the data into an array once and only once for data accuracy and speed.  For my skill level I am going to stick with the Array methodology.

My two approaches are:

- Use Global dimmed dynamic Arrays
- Dim the dynamic arrays in my Main procedure and pass them to the called procedures

So, what is Stack Overflow's take on the Pros vs Cons of these two methods?
Thanks,
Craig...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, to answer the question you specifically didn't ask: Set up a custom class and load the data in that.  Seriously, you'll thank me later.

OK, on to your question.  I start by limiting the scope as much as possible.  That means that I'm passing variables between procedures.  When all your variables have the most restrictive scope possible, you run into the fewest problems down the line.

Once a variable passes two levels deep (calling procedure to 1st tier, 1st tier to 2nd tier), then I start taking a critical look at my structure.  Usually (but not always) if all three procedures are in the same module, I'll create a module-level variable (use the Private keyword instead of Dim).  If you separate your modules correctly (not arbitrarily) you can have module-level variables without much risk.

There are some variables that are always global right from the start: the variable that holds the app name and app version; the top-level class module that should never lose scope as long as the app is running; the constants (I know they're not variables) that hold things like commandbar names.  I know I want these global, so they start that way.

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that module-level variables never migrate to global variables.  Global variables start out that way because of their nature.  If using a module-level variable seems cumbersome, it's probably because I've split a module up for no good reason or I need to rethink my whole framework.

That's not to say I've never cheated and used a global when I shouldn't have.  We've all done it and you shouldn't lose any sleep if you do it too.

So to properly book-end this post:  I quit using arrays unless I'm forced to.  I use custom classes because

```
ActiveCell.Value = Invoice.LocalSalesTaxAmount
```

is so much nicer to debug than

```
ActiveCell.Value = aInvoice(35,2)
```

Just in case you think you need more skill to work with custom classes - so did I.  I bit the bullet and so can anyone else.

Comment: So, three questions/points:  1st) You seem to differentiate between module level and global level variables, why?  Just the scope?  2nd) I use a custom type so that I can do arData(52,4).sStep and I can use a 2nd array as a pointer array to have another sort order, without duplicating the data.  3rd) So from the lack of a statement about it, I assume passing a 10x1000 array of a custom type of 20 variables is negligible so long as I do not do something silly, like using ByVal, when passing?

Comment: 1.  Yes, just scope.  When a variable is private to a module, the number of procedures that can change it is limited, which helps to prevent bugs.
2.  Types are just as good as classes if you're only storing properties, i.e. you don't need additional logic.
3.  I agree with that statement.

Comment: @dkusleika:  Can you explain your "i.e. you don't need additional logic" statement above?  What do you mean, like validation or something?  In 600 Characters or less :)  what additional logic would I gain?
Thanks...

Comment: @Craig, I think he means that classes have methods, whereas types don't.

Comment: @Craig echoing what Lance said, types merely provide a value, whereas classes can provide methods to extend the functionality of an object. The main benefit to what dkusleika is saying regarding classes is that instead of saying "I need the value from index 3 at the third dimension of this array," you can instead collect all your properties within a class and access that value explicitly.  Dkusleika's example code illustrates this nicely.

Comment: Right.  In addition to methods, you can have read-only properties.  e.g. you could have a read write property for UserName and a read-only property for UserInitials that is calculated off UserName.  FWIW, I never use Types anymore.  MZTools makes it so easy to set up a class that I use that even when a Type will suffice.

Comment: All right, I guess I've waited long enough, thanks for the answer and the subsequent comments.  Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful with globals in Excel VBA, because if your application hits any kind of bug, and does some kind of soft reset (but the app still functions), then the globals will have been erased.

I had to give up on globals, since I don't write perfect apps.

Comment: lol, there is no such thing as the perfect vba app, they all crash eventually given a complex enough environment.